# Gnuplot: Shrink axes to plot ("tight" axes)

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, axes

I have a datafile that I would like to create a `pm3d map` splot of. Code:

```
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set out "test.png"
set pm3d map
splot "fill.dat"
```

Problem is, with the odd (but regular) spacings using in the data, `gnuplot` creates a huge white margin around the actual image.
[image: basic result]

I want to look it like the following, but **without setting the x- and yrange manually**. I think I remember there being an option in `gnuplot` to achieve a 'tight' fitting of the axes, but I don't recall the actual command.

[image: desired result]

Content of file `fill.dat`

```
1.1 1.2 3
1.1 2.4 4
1.1 3.6 2

2.2 1.2 5
2.2 2.4 1
2.2 3.6 2

3.3 1.2 7
3.3 2.4 2
3.3 3.6 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use the command `set autoscale <axes>fix`:

```
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set out "test.png"
set pm3d map
set autoscale fix
splot "fill.dat"
```

Which gives you exactly the second image you posted.